# How to center an image in the viewport with unknown height?

Tags: image, center, vertical-alignment, viewport

I'm creating an image gallery using BxSlider (http://bxslider.com) and would like to center the image both horizontally and vertically in the viewport. I am also using a resizing script so don't know the dimensions of my images.

I have tried all kinds of scripts that I've found through Google but nothing seems to be working.

This is my html:

```
<div id="myDiv">

    <div><img src="" /></div>
    <div><img src="" /></div>
    <div><img src="" /></div>

</div>
```

My BxSlider code:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider/master/jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#myDiv').bxSlider({
       mode: 'fade',
       captions: true,
       });
   });
</script>
```

And my resizing code:

```
function resizeImg() {
    var h = $(window).height();
    if (840 > h) {
        var bw = h - 210;
        $('img').attr('height',bw);
        //alert('Height: '+h);
        // post-container-image
    }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var h = $(window).height();
    if (840 > h) {
        resizeImg();
    }
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    var h = $(window).height();
    if (840 > h) {
        resizeImg();
    }
});
```